# Parametize rmarkdown using meta block

Tags: r, r-markdown

To generate several rmarkdown reports is it possible to create a parameter in the meta block to set the title, modify the analysis and create the saved file name?

````
---
output: html_document
params:
  value_1: "99"
  value_2: "44"
title: "`r paste("Bunker ",params$value_1)`"
date: "11 May 2020"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(inputFile,encoding = encoding, output_file = file.path(dirname(inputFile), paste0(params$value_1,params_value_2,"_",Sys.Date(),".html"))) })
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r}

value_1 <- as.numeric(params$value_1)

ggplot()+
  aes(x=1:value_1,y=rnorm(n=value_1,0,2))+
  geom_point()

value_2 <- as.numeric(params$value_2)

ggplot()+
  aes(x=1:value_2,y=rnorm(n=value_2,0,2))+
  geom_point()


```
````

Comment: Check this answer https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports.html%23parameter_types%2F

Comment: Thanks Martin, that looks like it will work. Can you correct the code in an answer so I can accept it